Наличие и цены поставщиков 1С
Всем привет! Сейчас работаю над подключением сайта к 1С через протокол OData. Возник вопрос по получению данных о ценах и остатках товаров у поставщиков. По ссылке http://localhost/mc/odata/standard.odata/$metadata нет ни одного документа, отвечающего за наличие и стоимость товара у поставщиков, подскажите как ее получить?

Сведения о ценах и остатках в 1С хранятся в регистрах. Нужно делать к ним запрос.

@Sagittarius, у вас есть примеры такимх запросов? Мне еще нужно выгружать сопутствующие товары, характеристики и т.д. Их тоже брать из регистров?

Откуда брать, это надо смотреть конфигурацию. Примеров точных по запросам нет. Смотрите статьи в интернете, на профильных сайтах в контексте 1С (например, Infostart.ru). Либо ищите документацию по платформе. Но всё равно придется немного вникать в 1С тогда. Чтобы понять, откуда и какими запросами получать.

В рамках сайтов вопрос-ответ вряд ли вам прям кто-то разжует. Судя по всему, вы делаете интеграцию с 1С. Если у вас большой перечень задач, то лучше обратиться к специалисту за консультацией.

Например, статья - https://infostart.ru/1c/articles/1570140/
